# http post request change the order of json object in ios (ionic 3)

Tags: android, ios, json, ionic-framework, http-post

I am working on an ionic app which will be used on android and iOS platforms.and I need to post an object to the server which contain some attribute that reference others for example:

```
{
"room": [
 {
   "@id": 2,
   "date": "2019-10-10",
   "number": "750"
 }
],
"bed": [
[
  {
    "class": "A",
    "room": 2
  }
 ]
]
}
```

but when posting it the order of the JSON object changes to :

```
{
"bed": [
 [
   {
     "class": "A",
     "room": 2
   }
 ]
],
"room": [
  {
    "@id": 2,
    "date": "2019-10-10",
    "number": "750"
  }
 ]
 }
```

what should I do to keep the order of the object, considering that it works fine in android?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [JSON's standards](http://json.org), an object is simply unordered which means there is no problem with your case. However, if in your case the order is important, you may use arrays. Arrays make sure the order is preserved.

Comment: it's not working, because I have cant change in the server and it shows me that error "MongoError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead".

Comment: I think it has an issue with IOS because it works fine in android